# Is there a mathematical way to calculate the density, volume, etc of a planet just using mass as data?

Tags: planets, physics, solar-system, mathematics, alien-geometry

while I was working on the language I was thinking about the planet and I don't have the mathematical data, I have a fairly done map but not the data and it would be interesting to add it. As data I only made the mass, it is $4,185×10^{24} kg$.

Comment: I can't make a sense out of that sole number. And it also lacks a unit. Kg? Horses? Carats?

Comment: L.Dutch's answer is the right answer, you just need to pick the density. It's a planet with life, so you could simply choose Earth's density (5.51 g/cm^2). Or you could select the average density of the non-gas-giant planets in our system (Mercury 5.43, Mars 3.93, Venus 5.24 + Earth, avg = 5.03 g/cm^2). But without picking a density, you can't get the volume and radius. You could pick a radius first and find the density, but there's value to working with the solid planets we know.... or even just using Earth's density. Also, I assume you meant 10^24, not 24^10, right? They're not equal.

Comment: BTW, the reason you can't simply use one number is because the core of planets are different. Planets without a liquid core have a much higher density than planets with a liquid core. Liquid cores are, I believe, required to have a good magnetosphere, which would help rationalize life. There's a lot of interconnectedness that's bound to just two numbers: mass and density, but you need both. I believe a super-low-density planet is highly unlikely to support life, as would a super-high-density planet.

Comment: Hi, yes, it was the other way around, it's 10^24 not 24^10 I was in the wrong place because I was writing this with some sleep

Comment: And does the density have to be different from the mass? it is because I am afraid that it does not make sense with the mass of the planet that is why I asked if it was possible

Comment: @JBH It won't let me edit it because I made a mistake several times in a comment trying to mention you

Comment: As L.Dutch explained, density differs from mass. Density describes the mass inside a volume. Look at it this way: if you pour 100g of water into a glass (don't worry about the volume of the glass) you can see that it fills some amount of the glass. Then you *freeze* it. Frozen water has a lower density than liquid water - and you can see that in the glass *because it fills more of the glass' volume.* This is why you need two of the three numbers. Mass and volume, mass and density, or volume and density. If you know the two, you can get the third. But you can't do it with just one.

Comment: In your mass, is the comma denoting a decimal place (european style) or thousands (american style)?

Comment: European, because if I transfer it to tons it would be something else

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Alogrithm outline

So like L. Dutch said, if you assume the volume or average density of the planet you can do this. But the volume and average density aren't first principles values-- they themselves depend on the material and composition in a way that I'll describe shortly. **As a word of warning-- I'm going to assume you understand calculus for this-- if you don't, L. Dutch's answer is about as good as you can do.**

So, the fundamental difficulty of this problem is that to know the mass of the planet, you need to know the density distribution. The other answer assumes that it's constant, but this isn't a well founded assumption-- the inside of the planet has a lot more pressure squeezing down on it, which leads to higher densities. So how do we deal with this difficulty? Why, with differential equations of course! Barring any funny business like a quickly rotating planet or one that's still accreting, the main equation you would use is the hydrostatic equilibrium equation which basically says that the pressure pushing up against a thin shell of material must exactly cancel the force of gravity pulling it down:

$$\frac{dP}{dr} = -\frac{Gm(r)}{r^2} \rho(r)$$

where $r$ is the radial distance from the planet's center, $P(r)$ is the pressure at that depth, $\rho(r)$ the density, and $G$ the gravitational constant. $m(r)$ is a function that gives you the mass inside the sphere of radius $r$, and as such $m(r) = \int_0^r 4 \pi r^2 \rho(r') dr'$. But we want a system of differential equations to solve, so we differentiate this to get

$$\frac{dm}{dr} = 4 \pi r^2 \rho(r)$$

Now, we just want to integrate this system of equations incorporating your boundary condition. Hold on though, we're not quite ready-- there are three functions we want to determine: $\rho$, $P$, and $m$, but only two equations. We need another equation to solve this thing!

That equation comes in the form of the so-called equation of state, which is where the planetary composition comes in. It turns out that for a given material, there's a function that relates the density and pressure called the equation of state (which we'll denote by $g$):

$$g(\rho, P) = 0$$

I should mention first off that the EOS also relates another variable to these two-- usually temperature, entropy, or specific internal energy. However the purposes of determining density profiles, the effects are pretty small (~a few %) so you can usually just set the temp to some reasonable value like 5,000 K and pull g from along that isotherm.

Now, things can get a little tricky here-- the equation of state isn't guaranteed to give rise to a one-to-one relationship between density and pressure. In other words, we can't necessarily write $P = f(\rho)$ and $\rho = f^{-1}(P)$. If this is the case, we have to use a solver for what's known as a [differential-algebraic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential-algebraic_system_of_equations). You can mimic this behavior using a [normal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23578596/solve-an-implicit-ode-differential-algebraic-equation-dae) ODE package available in most languages, but it might be pretty slow. Another option is the language Julia, which has a great differential equations package that can solve [algebraic-differential equations](https://diffeq.sciml.ai/stable/tutorials/dae_example/). Usually for this regime though, we can at least write $P = f(\rho)$ even though we can't invert it, which for this specific system of equations is good enough to rewrite them as:

$$\frac{d \rho}{dr} = -\frac{Gm(r)}{r^2 f'} \rho(r)$$

$$\frac{dm}{dr} = 4 \pi r^2 \rho(r)$$

Now, how do we find an EOS for a given material? Well there are several ways:

1. The most common in the field of planetary science is to use a premade table generated by someone who knows more about EOS's than you do. [SESAME](https://www.lanl.gov/org/ddste/aldsc/theoretical/physics-chemistry-materials/sesame-database.php) and [FPEOS](http://militzer.berkeley.edu/FPEOS/) are two I know of-- the latter is easy to access but unfortunately doesn't have a lot of important elements (most notably iron, which is important for rocky planets). The former is more complete but you have to request access through the link I gave. Either way with this option you'll have to spend some time learning other scripts or writing your own scripts to parse the tables.
2. You can muck about the literature to find a paper with a formula or plot that you can [digitize](https://automeris.io/WebPlotDigitizer/), like [this one](https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/6345571).
3. You can just give some kind of empirical formula you think seems reasonable enough. Power law relationships like $P = C\rho^{\gamma}$ are often popular for this.

Phew, we finally have our equations set up! Now we just need to use our boundary conditions: if $R$ is the radius of your planet, this condition is that $m(R) = M$, where $M$ is the mass you wish the planet to have. But unfortunately, since we don't know what $R$ should be we have to take an iterative approach described by the following control flow:

1. Set $m(r = \epsilon) = 0$ and $\rho(r = \epsilon) = \rho_{guess}$. Here $\epsilon$ is a small positive number but not quite $0$ because our equations are singular there. Can probably do a change of variable to fix this but it's less physically clear what's going on and I'm also lazy.
2. Solve the two coupled equations above until you get the radius $R$ such that $P(R) = f(\rho(R)) = 0$ (since there is no pressure at the surface of the planet). Might have to use some small positive pressure other than zero for numerical reasons.
3. Check $M(R)$.

- If it's close enough to the mass you want, you're done! Extract the density and pressure profiles from the ODE solution.
- If it's too big, make $\rho_{guess}$ smaller and repeat step 2
- If it's too small, make $\rho_{guess}$ bigger and repeat step 2

And that's all there is to it! If I have time later I'll try to add a simple example script to use but hopefully that's enough to get you started.

### EDIT: Pictures and a simple code

So I made a simple python code to calculate planetary masses, the result is below. It should be pretty easy to use, all you need to do is have the appropriate packages installed and change Mdesired and the equation of state function to your liking:

```
import scipy.interpolate as interp
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.integrate as sciint
from math import pi

G = 6.67408e-11   # gravitational constant in [m^3][kg^-1][s^-2]
rho_guess = 1e4   # initial guess for center of planet density in [kg][m^-3]
Mdesired = 6e24          # Desired planet mass in [kg]

# Now we normalize units so that G, M, rho_guess=1.
# This will help numerical stability.
rhostar = rho_guess
Mstar = Mdesired
Tstar = (G * rhostar)**(-1/2)
Lstar = (Mstar / rhostar)**(1/3)
Pstar = Mstar / (Lstar * Tstar**2)
Mdesired = Mdesired / Mstar
rho_guess = rho_guess / rhostar
M0 = 0.0
eps = 1e-4  # start ODE at this value of r to avoid singularity

def dudr(r, u):
    # u[0] = rho, u[1] = m
    drhodr = -(u[1]/(r**2 * dPdrho(u[0])) * u[0])
    dmdr = 4*pi*r**2*u[0]
    return [drhodr, dmdr]

def P(rho):
    """EOS of epsilon iron phase from OSTI 6345571 
    """
    rho0 = 8.430*1e3 / rhostar
    beta0 = 182*1e9 / Pstar
    betaprime0 = 5.0
    eta = rho/rho0

    P = 1.5*beta0*((eta**(7/3) - eta**(5/3))
                   *(1 + (3/4)*(eta**(2/3) - 1)*(betaprime0 - 4)))
    return P

rho_EOS_arr = np.linspace(0, 50, 1000)
dPdrho_arr = np.gradient(P(rho_EOS_arr), rho_EOS_arr)
dPdrho = interp.interp1d(rho_EOS_arr, dPdrho_arr, bounds_error=False, 
                         fill_value=(0.0, 0.0))

def found_surface(r, u):
    """Event that terminates ODE when surface is reached
    """
    Psurf = 1e-7 
    return P(u[0]) - Psurf
found_surface.terminal = True

def M(rho_guess, plot=False, obj = False):
    """Find mass of planet given guess for density at center.
    Can also plot density profiles and give ODE solution object
    """
    sol = sciint.solve_ivp(dudr, (eps, 100), (rho_guess, M0),
                           events = found_surface, 
                           t_eval = np.linspace(eps, 50, 10000))

    if plot:
        plt.figure()
        plt.plot(sol.t*Lstar/1e3, sol.y[0,:]*rhostar/1e3)
        plt.title(r"$\rho$ vs $r$")
        plt.xlabel(r"$r$ $(km)$")
        plt.ylabel(r"$\rho$ $(g/cm^3)$")
        
        plt.figure()
        plt.plot(sol.t*Lstar/1e3, sol.y[1,:]*Mstar/1e3)
        plt.title(r"$M$ vs $r$")
        plt.xlabel(r"$r$ $(km)$")
        plt.ylabel(r"$M$ $(kg)$")
    
    if obj:    
        return sol
    else:
        return sol.y[1,-1]

rhoc = opt.newton(lambda rho: M(rho) - Mdesired, rho_guess, tol = 1e-3, maxiter=200)
                      
sol = M(rhoc, plot=True, obj=True)
print(f"radius is {sol.t[-1]*Lstar/1e3} km")
print(f"mass is {sol.y[1,-1]*Mstar:e} kg")

plt.show()
```

Right now, I have it set up so that `Mdesired` is the mass of Earth in order to benchmark it. Here's what it predicts for the density profile of Earth[image]. It's not *terribly* wrong-- it predicts Earth's radius is ~5000 km instead of ~6400 km. It also has a somewhat similar density profile to the core.

The main reason for the discrepancy is that this calculation assumes the entire Earth is Iron in the $\epsilon$ phase-- this is really only true for the core and so it describes the crust and mantle as too dense and the end result is that it under predicts the radius of Earth. To fix this, you'd have to modify the equation of state so that its value changes with $m(r)$. This is a good exercise and if you understood this at all I recommend trying it out!

### EDIT 2: A more accurate code

So I really went and [nerd sniped](https://xkcd.com/356/) myself on this one. Below is a code I developed that I think in principle can give you the exact density profiles you see in the literature (sans temperature corrections) as long as you have appropriate equations of state. **I realized that I made a mistake in my last edit when describing the path forward for multiple EOSs-- if you just make the EOS abruptly vary by $m(r)$ at material boundaries, it will give unphysical results.** The reason is that the code implicitly assumes a continuous density profile, when in reality it is the pressure profile that is continuous.

There are a couple of ways to deal with this, but what my code does is it solves for the density profile one material at a time, stitching together at the interfaces with the correct boundary conditions. As inputs, you need:

1. A desired mass for the planet in $kg$
2. A guess at the density in the center of the planet in $kg/m^3$. This doesn't have to be super accurate-- ~10000 will probably work, but if you're working with very high or low masses you may need to adjust to get the solvers to converge
3. A collection of materials that define your planet's composition. There are two lists corresponding to this item: one gives the fraction of total planetary mass for each material, and one is a list of equations of state for each material. I've included ones for iron and silicate perovskite which is a good approximation for Earth, but if you want other materials just peruse the literature and find more formulas.

**And thats it!** All you need to change are the variables in the input section, everything else should do the heavy lifting. Without any further ado, here's the code:

```
import scipy.interpolate as interp
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.integrate as sciint
from math import pi

#####################################
###### INPUTS #######################
#####################################

def P_silicates(rho):
    """EOS of cold silicate perovskite from Bina 1995
    """
    Ktau0 = 262*1e9 / Pstar
    Kprimetau0 = 4
    rho0 = 4.1 * 1e3 / rhostar
    f = 0.5*((rho/rho0)**(2/3) - 1)
    xi = -(3/4)*(Kprimetau0 - 4)
    Pc = 3*Ktau0*f*(1+2*f)**(5/2)*(1-xi*f)
   
    return Pc

def P_iron(rho):
    """EOS of epsilon iron phase from OSTI 6345571 
    """
    rho0 = 8.430*1e3 / rhostar
    beta0 = 182*1e9 / Pstar
    betaprime0 = 5.0
    eta = rho/rho0
    
    Pc = 1.5*beta0*((eta**(7/3) - eta**(5/3))
                    *(1 + (3/4)*(eta**(2/3) - 1)*(betaprime0 - 4)))
    return Pc

G = 6.67408e-11   # gravitational constant in [m^3][kg^-1][s^-2]
rho0_guess = 1e4   # initial guess for center of planet density in [kg][m^-3]
Mdesired = 6e24          # Desired planet mass in [kg]
mat_Mfracs = [0.3, 0.7]  # Mass fraction for each material type, starting from
                         # core outward
mat_EOSs = [P_iron, P_silicates]  # EOS for each material type


##############################################
######## SOLVER ##############################
##############################################

# Now we normalize units so that G, M, rho_guess=1.
# This will help numerical stability.
msum = sum(mat_Mfracs)
mat_Mfracs = [val/msum for val in mat_Mfracs]
rhostar = rho0_guess
Mstar = Mdesired
Tstar = (G * rhostar)**(-1/2)
Lstar = (Mstar / rhostar)**(1/3)
Pstar = Mstar / (Lstar * Tstar**2)
Mdesired = Mdesired / Mstar
rho0_guess = rho0_guess / rhostar
M0 = 0.0

def dudr(r, u, Mdesired, mat_props):
    # u[0] = rho, u[1] = m
    drhodr = -(u[1]/(r**2 * dPdrho(*u, Mdesired, mat_props)) * u[0])
    dmdr = 4*pi*r**2*u[0]
    return [drhodr, dmdr]

def dPdrho(rho, m, Mdesired, mat_props):
    Pfunc = mat_props["Pfunc"]
    drho = 1e-9
    P1 = Pfunc(rho+drho)
    Pn1 = Pfunc(rho-drho)
    return (P1 - Pn1) / (2*drho)

def end_of_material(r, u, Mdesired, mat_props):
    """Event that terminates ODE when the end of a shell for a given material 
    is reached.
    """
    cum_mass_frac_end = mat_props["cum_mass_frac_end"]
    return u[1]/Mdesired - cum_mass_frac_end
end_of_material.terminal = True    

def found_surface(r, u, Mdesired, mat_props):
    """Event that terminates ODE when surface is reached
    """
    Psurf = 1e-7 
    Pfunc = mat_props["Pfunc"]
    return Pfunc(u[0]) - Psurf
found_surface.terminal = True

def solve_one_mat(rho0, m0, Mdesired, mat_props):
    r0 = mat_props["r0"]
    last_mat = mat_props["last_mat"]
    if last_mat:
        sol = sciint.solve_ivp(
            dudr, (r0, 100), (rho0, m0),
            args = (Mdesired, mat_props),
            events = found_surface, 
            t_eval = np.linspace(r0, 100, 100000),
            tol = 1e-8
            )
    else:
        sol = sciint.solve_ivp(
            dudr, (r0, 100), (rho0, m0),
            args = (Mdesired, mat_props),
            events = (found_surface, end_of_material), 
            t_eval = np.linspace(r0, 100, 100000),
            tol = 1e-8
            )
    return sol

def M(rho0, Mdesired, mat_Mfracs, mat_EOSs, plot=False):
    """Find mass of planet given guess for density at center.
    Can also plot density profiles and give ODE solution object
    """
    cumsum_Mfracs = np.cumsum(mat_Mfracs)
    rho0, m0, r0 = [rho0, 0.0, 1e-7]  # solver starts at 1e-7 radius to avoid
                                      # singularity
    P0 = mat_EOSs[0](rho0)
    r_arr = np.array([])
    rho_arr = np.array([])
    m_arr = np.array([])
    
    for i in range(len(mat_Mfracs)):
        # Build the mat_props dict for a given material, this tells the
        # solver what material we're using
        mat_props = {}
        mat_props["Pfunc"] = mat_EOSs[i]
        mat_props["cum_mass_frac_end"] = cumsum_Mfracs[i]
        mat_props["r0"] = r0
        mat_props["last_mat"] = (i == len(mat_EOSs)-1)
        rho0 = opt.newton(lambda rho: mat_EOSs[i](rho) - P0, rho0, tol = 1e-8)
        
        sol = solve_one_mat(rho0, m0, Mdesired, mat_props)        
        rho0, m0, r0 = [sol.y[0,-1], sol.y[1,-1], sol.t[-1]]
        P0 = mat_EOSs[i](rho0)
        r_arr = np.concatenate((r_arr, sol.t))
        rho_arr = np.concatenate((rho_arr, sol.y[0,:]))
        m_arr = np.concatenate((m_arr, sol.y[1,:]))
        
        # If surface is reached before we can get through all materials,
        # we must end the loop
        if len(sol.t_events[0]) != 0 and not(mat_props["last_mat"]):
            missed_layers = True
            break
        else: 
            missed_layers = False
    
    if plot:
        plt.figure()
        plt.plot(r_arr*Lstar/1e3, rho_arr*rhostar/1e3)
        plt.title(r"$\rho$ vs $r$")
        plt.xlabel(r"$r$ $(km)$")
        plt.ylabel(r"$\rho$ $(g/cm^3)$")
        
        plt.figure()
        plt.plot(r_arr*Lstar/1e3, m_arr*Mstar)
        plt.title(r"$M$ vs $r$")
        plt.xlabel(r"$r$ $(km)$")
        plt.ylabel(r"$M$ $(kg)$")
    
    return (m_arr[-1], r_arr, rho_arr, m_arr, missed_layers)

# Solve for density at planet center that gives the desired planetary mass
rhoc = opt.newton(
    lambda rho0: M(rho0, Mdesired, mat_Mfracs, mat_EOSs)[0] - Mdesired, 
    rho0_guess, tol = 1e-4, maxiter = 200
    )
# Solve for and plot final values                          
R, r_arr, rho_arr, m_arr, missed_layers = M(
    rhoc, Mdesired, mat_Mfracs, mat_EOSs, plot=True
    )
print(f"radius is {r_arr[-1]*Lstar/1e3} km")
print(f"mass is {m_arr[-1]*Mstar:e} kg")
```

Right now I have some input parameters that are roughly correct for Earth, namely $M_{desired} = 6\times 10^{24} kg$, with a composition of 30% Iron and 70% silicates. So how does it do? Pretty well, actually! Here's the density profile it outputs:

[image]

Which is pretty close to the types of profiles you'll see if you do a quick google search! It also estimates Earth's radius as 6250 km, pretty damn close to the actual value of 6370 km. Hopefully this was useful for you!

### A couple of simplifications I've made if you want to dig in more

1. I ignore temperature dependence. In reality, the EOS will relate 3 variables and you'll need a third equation that tells you how temperature varies with depth. This is a trickier equation because it depends on time from accretion and radioactive decay and a whole bunch of other stuff that you need to specify.
2. In reality, the form of the EOS won't be the EOS for a single material-- as you go deeper, planetary composition changes. Tbh I'm not sure how you calculate this from first principles-- there's probably some sort of thermodynamic/buoyancy argument to be made but I'm not certain. **EDIT--** my second code addresses this when there are clear boundaries between material types. In reality there will be a transition zone of some thickness, but it seems like more of the literature ignores this anyway.
3. If there are other forces on your planet like centripetal forces from spinning, that can change the pressure balance equation.
4. For super heavy objects like neutron stars, you have to take GR into account via the [Tolman-Oppenheimer-Volkoff Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tolman%E2%80%93Oppenheimer%E2%80%93Volkoff_equation)

Comment: Re constant density not being a well-founded assumption, you need to be stronger than that.  In most cases (if not all), it's a false assumption, because the planet differentiates.  For instance, Earth has a layer of crust at 2.7-3.3, mantle 3.3-5.7, and core 9.9-13.0 (all gm/cm^3).

Comment: @jamesqf Pretty much every model that's actually solvable is gonna have "false" assumptions in it-- it's all a question of how precise of an answer you want. If you wanted to be as accurate as possible you'd have to do something like an ensemble of lattice qft simulations with states of many quadrillions of particles. Of course that's completely unfeasible to compute so we introduce many, many layers of simplification-- if the OP wants an order of magnitude estimate it's not unreasonable to look up typical average densities of the type of planet you're interested in and use L. Dutch's method

Comment: Thanks, right now I'm going to try

Comment: @el duderino: I'm pretty sure that it's not solvable, in the sense of giving a unique answer, because I doubt there is one.  I would guess that there are a great many possible combinations of materials and shell diameters that would fit the given mass & radius.  But you could make some assumptions about shell radii & densities, and write a program to converge on a possible solution.

Comment: @jamesqf It's true that there likely are many possible material combos that can give the same mass and radius without further info like their relative ratios. Still because most materials in planets behave very roughly the same, you can still get a very rough idea of the radius of a planet given it's mass if you look at average densities of other planets with similar masses. However, I just posted a code that gives much more accurate results so you might find that interesting!

Answer (score 3):

To calculate the density $\rho$ or the volume $V$ of a body, you can use the relationship $\rho=M/V$.

Being two unknown values and a single equation, you can't solve it unless you have some other constrain to throw in. If you can give for example the radius, you can calculate the volume as $V=4/3 \pi r^3$ and from there the density.

Another possible extrapolation is that, if you assume the average density to be same as Earth or any other planet you might want to consider, than from the density you can calculate the volume.

Comment: Doesn;t work unless you make assumptions about the mass distribution.  You could have an average density the same as Earth's, but a heavier core and lighter mantle, or vice versa.